# jQuery UI droppable on start firing ajax request is firing multiple itmes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Hi I'm using jQuery UI more specifically I am using draggable and droppable. When the user starts dragging the element I fire an ajax request that will disable this for other users. However this is firing twice instead of once and I'm not sure why. My code is below:

```
$("ul.draggable li").draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                containment: "document",
                start: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log('start drag...disable item for all other users');
                    var id = $(this).attr('data-taskprogress-id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/task/board/disableTask/' + id,
                        async: true,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (json) {
                            var Successmessage = JSON.stringify(json.message);
                            toastr.success(Successmessage);

                            taskBoard.update('/task/board/fetchScrumBoardView/'+sprint_id );

                        } // end success

                    }); // end ajax
                }, // end start
            });
```

Is there a way I can ensure that this is run only once at least until a response is feed back?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fire an ajax call whenever a `ul.draggable li` gets dragged since you are always firing the ajax with no restrictions, that's why it is occurring more than once.

To make sure a single ajax is running you need to make some specific handling :

[ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) registers a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins,  and once all Ajax requests have completed [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) is called.

What you can do is identify your calls, give each call an id and put it within a queue (actually an array but has a specific handling).

Whenever the drag function is called, you can check if the queue is empty then make the ajax call and set a global js flag that says an ajax is running to true. Otherwise, add the id requesting the ajax to the queue.

On ajax stop, check if the queue is empty, if so set the flag to false, otherwise call the ajax function with the next id and remove it from the queue.

This is some brain storming that shall put you on the track.